# Rails printing address labels in text file in this format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application that stores the address of subscribers of a magazine. It should allow download of addresses as labels in a text file so it can be printed by a dot-matrix printer.

Each subscriber has a `name`, `name_prefix` ("Mr.", "Miss", etc.), `address`, `area`, `zipcode`, etc.

The output should have the following format:

```
g51/b18468 Postgg On 30/05/2013      N51/b39897 Postgg On 30/05/2013      LR51/b23428 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Rgv. XXXXX                           Mr. bBnMbNNbN.M                      Bro. bBRbgbM .S,
KbgbNg bSSgMBLY Og gOg,              LOT 92, KbMPUNg                      gRbgg gOMMUNnTY ggNTRg,
52, gLN. TnMUR,                      BbTU 4, 43950                        4, LORONg SS 23/6g,
POST BOX 20, 43007 KbgbNg            SUNgbn PgLnK                         47400 PgTbLnNg gbYb,
MbLbYSnb                             SgLbNgUR                             SgLbNgOR, W.MbLbYSnb
                                     MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb


ML51/b13179 Postgg On 30/05/2013     W51/b41363 Postgg On 30/05/2013      Lg51/b29053 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Bro. bBRbgbM .V                      Bro. bLbPPbN                         Pbstor. bLgRgg PRbgbSbM
NO:18,PgRSnbRbN                      NO.60, LORONg SgRbn PgRMbn 9,        1-2-2, MggbN nNTbN bPbRTMgNT,
RnSgbg .7                            TbMbN SgRbn PgRMbn,                  gbLbN 1/21g Ogg gbLbN gOMBbK
TbMbN RnSgbg                         34300, BbTbN SgRbn,                  53000 KUbLb LUMPUR
30100 nPOg, PgRbK                    PgRbK                                MbLbYSnb
MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb


LR510b13172 Postgg On 30/05/2013     ML51/b9877 Postgg On 30/05/2013      LR51/b9905 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Sns. bLLbMbg (b) NgSbM               Bro. bLVnN bNbNg .b                  Mrs. bNnTgb VngTOR
NO:44,gbLbN gbMbn                    NO:3,gbLbN TgRbTbn 3                 7,gbLbN PbRn
TbMbN TbPbg gbYb                     TbMbN SbRn,TgRbTbn                   PbRn gbRggNS
35000 TbPbg                          44000 KUbLb KUBU BgbRU               nPOg,30100
PgRbK,                               SgLbNgOR                             PgRbK
MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb


ML51/b13180 Postgg On 30/05/2013     ML51/b13203 Postgg On 30/05/2013     g51/b9942 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Bro. bNTONY                          Bro. bNTONYSWbMY                     Pbstor. bROKnbNbTgbN
NO:399,LORONg KgNbVn 3/2b            LbgbNg gUSUN gURnbM                  NO:M4 g/7
TbMbN KgNbRn                         42700 BbNTnNg                        gbLbN PbNgbN nNgbg 4/1b
09000 KULnM                          SgLbNgOR g.g                         PbNgbN nNgbg
Kggbg                                MbLbYSnb                             55100,KUbLb LUMPUR
MbLbYSnb                                                                  MbLbYSnb
```

I have scrambled names and addresses.

So basically each label will be like this:

```
<MemberCode> Posted on <Date>
Mr. Steve Robinson
No: 35, Buther Street,
Kamaraj Nagar, Avadi
Chennai - 600071
```

Only if the column width is of above labels' format the printer prints in the label sheet.

How do I print this kind of text file from Rails?

I've tried [Prawn/Labels](https://github.com/jordanbyron/prawn-labels) PDF creator, but PDF printing sucks in our dot matrix.

How does one do this?

UPDATE:

I saw a vote saying its unclear. 
I want to click a button that will download a text file containing all the addresses in the specified format. I want to print addresses in this three column format with precise column widths and number of lines for each row. I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee the width of each line in a column will not exceed the width of the column, you can create padded strings using `sprintf`.  Each of your columns is 37 characters wide, so to print three columns, the command would be `sprintf("%-37s%-37s%-37s", col1,col2,col3)`.  You would have to repeat that for each field.  That's assuming you have a string already for each line.  You will need to generate each string from your data for things like concatenating the prefix with the name.

Comment: Note, if any of the strings you're inserting is longer than 37, `sprintf` will not automatically truncate it and it will throw off all columns on that row.  `"%-37.37s"` will truncate at 37 characters.  `"%-37.30s"` will truncate at 30 characters, etc.

Comment: Okay so... I have subscribers array with their records. Now I do each_slice to generate a 2d array with 3 columns. Then I do a each loop and in each iteration I generate strings for each line and print them. I'll try and let you know! :) thank you..